# explode causing undefined offset

Tags: php

```
$arNotes = explode('<br>',$value[0]['notes']);
$arGenStatus = explode(':', $arNotes[1]);
$genStatusValue = explode('->', trim(preg_replace('/; /','',$arGenStatus[1])), 2);
var_dump($genStatusValue); exit;
```

When I var_dump or echo the array, I produce the following value.

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "closed " [1]=> string(10) " cancelled" }
```

However, the one below produce undefined offset 1 error

```
if ($genStatusValue[1] == 'cancelled') {
    $op = '+';
}
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($arGenStatus)`?

Comment: @aldrin27 Array ( [0] => general status [1] => closed -> cancelled; )

Comment: @aldrin27 could this be a bug? I'm using php 5.6.14

Comment: Why not use `foreach` and `in_array()` function?

Comment: @aldrin27 You're right. I almost forgot about in_array. Thanks!

Comment: one more thing, in your vardump result, you got one space after close, and one break before cancelled, so your condition will not return true either.

Comment: i tried reading your code again again, may be i am sleeping, or you are using vardump and your if statement are not at the same place, it should not give you the error, if you vardump result is this, and i dont know how foreach or in array going to help you.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you would provide the value of `$value[0]['notes']` at the start of the code, then we can run it ourselves.

Comment: If this code runs more than once then it could be that in a second iteration the `$arGenStatus` array no longer has the character sequence `->`. In that case the code will indeed fail at the point you indicate. And if your `var_dump` was occurring after the offending `if`, then you would have the previous iteration's result dumped, and jump to wrong conclusions. Otherwise I see no problem with your code. It runs fine in [php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You execute that code multiple times. The first time it's all fine and dandy.

Unfortunately you use `exit` (don't!), so you don't see the next time when it's actually failing.

Remove the `exit` at witness the problem with `var_dump`.

---

As a sidenote: "could this be a bug? I'm using php 5.6.14" - That's a *very bad* attitude.

The First Rule of Programming: [It's Always Your Fault.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)